# Pandas DataFrame adding two zeros

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Hi can some one explain why it adds two 0 0 to my data frame in this function

```
def ToDF(ticker):
    marketPriceP = []
    marketPriceT = []    
    marketPriceT.append(t())
    marketPriceP.append(currentPrice(ticker))
    while True:
        marketPriceT.append(t())
        marketPriceP.append(currentPrice(ticker))
        if len(marketPriceP) > 5:
            MKpriceDF = pd.DataFrame(['Price'])
            MKpriceDF1 = pd.DataFrame(['Time'])
            MKpriceDF = MKpriceDF.append(marketPriceP, ignore_index= True, verify_integrity= False, sort= None)
            MKpriceDF1 = MKpriceDF1.append(marketPriceT, ignore_index= True, verify_integrity= False, sort= None)
            MKpriceDF = pd.concat([MKpriceDF1, MKpriceDF], axis= 1)
            return MKpriceDF
            break
```

the output looks like

```
          0      0
0      Time  Price
1  22:24:52  41.04
2  22:24:52  41.04
3  22:24:52  41.04
4  22:24:52  41.04
5  22:24:52  41.04
6  22:24:52  41.04
```

Comment: The code is very inefficient in the use of variables and time. To address why the problem arises, it's because of an incorrect call of `pd.DataFrame`

Comment: that's because you didn't explicitly provide a column name. so it defaults `0` as a column header

Comment: how should I have named the columns I thought i did but I see I just assigned them a value

Comment: you dont need a break after return.

Comment: `pd.DataFrame(['Price'])` is just creating a row with value `Price` not creating a column `Price`. If you want to create a column `Price`, you have to give `columns = ['Price']`

Comment: Instead of creating the datafame like that, why don't you just create two lists, then at the end of the while loop before you use the return, create the dataframe with the two columns and send it back

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to revisit how you are creating the dataframe. Here are some changes for you to consider. I have limited information about what you are doing so my answer is catering to just the code I have seen.

```
def ToDF(ticker):
    marketPriceP = []
    marketPriceT = []    
    marketPriceT.append(t())
    marketPriceP.append(currentPrice(ticker))
    while True:
        marketPriceT.append(t())
        marketPriceP.append(currentPrice(ticker))
        if len(marketPriceP) > 5:
            MKpriceDF = pd.DataFrame({'Price':marketPriceP, 'Time':marketPriceT})
            return MKpriceDF

        #    MKpriceDF = pd.DataFrame(['Price'])
        #    MKpriceDF1 = pd.DataFrame(['Time'])
        #    MKpriceDF = MKpriceDF.append(marketPriceP, ignore_index= True, verify_integrity= False, sort= None)
        #    MKpriceDF1 = MKpriceDF1.append(marketPriceT, ignore_index= True, verify_integrity= False, sort= None)
        #    MKpriceDF = pd.concat([MKpriceDF1, MKpriceDF], axis= 1)
        #    return MKpriceDF
        #    break
```